# Apple's FaceTime on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apple, emulation, ios, ubuntu-emulator

I wanted to know if Apple's FaceTime, designed for iOS, could work on Ubuntu 18.04 as well. Maybe through an emulator.
Do you know if there is any way to install FaceTime on Ubuntu? 
Or do I need an emulator? Which one?

Answer (score 4):

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8373587 No.

Easiest method would be virtualbox with macos if you really need Face Time.

Comment: So there is a way to install a virtualbox for iOS-based programs on Ubuntu?

Comment: ofcourse. you can install almost any OS in a virtualbox.

Comment: I installed virtual box and the drivers and image for mac didn't work. i got errorsa and a shell prompt but no way to bring up UI

Comment: That's not an Ubuntu issue. MacOS inside virtualbox  is possible. BTW: in case you downvoted ... the answer is NO and is correct.